# Ubuntu-based Distribution Building: SKEL cannot be read by a normal user inside live system

Tags: ubuntu

I'm making a distribution based off of Ubuntu called 'feren OS' but I'm having trouble finding a way to make the folders added into the Folder of the root system read-only inside the Live Session itself and instead, it just remains 'List files only' meaning that the feren OS SKEL changes are making no effect on the Live User and most likely, the installed system's user...

I've tried everything in the chroot I could think of: Setting permissions with the Terminal command, uploading and re-downloading the folder on a Drive, etc but to no avail...

**UPDATE: Fixed it now, the checked answer is what you need to do if you end up with the same situation as I did.**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I've now fixed it, what I did was use a tutorial on the Ubuntu Forums to make a DEB file with the (unreadable) folders inside it but set as read-only by anyone and then installed it from the Deb via Chroot and that somehow fixed it and now newly created users work properly. Development can now finish as normal of the OS...